# Postfix no longer reciving mail

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

I installed and configured a mail server with postfix(3.1.0-1)+dovecot(2.2.21) on archlinux(4.4.3-1) in December, and on which in confirmed it to be working, both receiving and sending.

About a week ago  I lost the ability to receive email and to send from Thunderbird. When trying to send, Thunderbird claims that it con't connect to the server over SMTP.

I can send using the **sendmail recipient** from the server and receive email locally. This made med think about wrongly forwarded ports but they are all still point to the right position. Secondly I thought about DNS - issues, but the .zone has not been changed.

I have been looking around but found nothing that helps to explain this. journalctl does not show any signs of errors.

Below follows my current settings.

```
postconf -n
--------
alias_database = $alias_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
command_directory = /usr/bin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/bin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd    $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = gserv.se
myhostname = mail.gserv.se
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
relay_domains =
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mail.gserv.se.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.gserv.se.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

This have been driving me crazy for a while now, it would be great to have another perspective.

Thanks

EDIT:
Adding current versions

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem.

Found out that nothing was listening to port 25 and it lead me to master.cf.

I have no idea how this came to be, but for some reason the SMTP line in master.cf was un-commented. After finxing that the server once more responded again.